# React: get DOM position for one of the children of component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a very annoying issue, and I need help with my component. It is used in such context:

```
<table>
  <thead>/* ... */</thead>
  <tbody>
    <COMPONENT>
      <ChildComponent>/* ... */</ChildComponent>
      <ChildComponent>/* ... */</ChildComponent>
      <ChildComponent>/* ... */</ChildComponent>
    </COMPONENT>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**ChildComponent** is a component that includes other components but eventually renders simple HTML's `<tr>`

inside **component.tsx**, I need to get DOM values (offsetTop and clientHeight) for n-th child.

I've tried many things:

- `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(children[n])` gives me:

> argument appears to not be a ReactComponent. Keys: $$typeof, type, key, ref, props, _owner, _store

- `children[n].ref` just gives me null
- cannot add ref to children
- This sort of works:

```
children.map((child, index) =>
    index === n ? (
        <div style={{display: contents}} key={index} ref={ref}>
    ) : child
)
```

gives me warning (but works!):

> index.js:2178 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...):  cannot appear as a child of .
>       in tr (created by FoldControlContainer) ...

is there a better solution? I've tried to use <>,  or other "transparent" to DOM components instead of `div`, but it didn't work.

Comment: What's `Tr`? Please, provide it. *children[n].ref just gives me null* - why should `ref` exist? *cannot add ref to children* - why?

Comment: Ah sorry, forgot about that, but that's a regular tr :). I'll update my code

Comment: In case it's `<tr>`, you would be able to get DOM element with a ref. What exactly did you try with refs?

Comment: @estus: well, I couldn't just children[n].ref = myRef, maybe there's some function for that but couldn't find it

Comment: @estus: Well it's not exactly `<tr>`, it's a class component that renders some other components that will eventually render `<tr>`. You're saying that if that would be a directly <tr> as a child, children[n].ref wouldn't be null?

Comment: No, there won't be `ref` if you didn't provided a ref, https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html . I'll try to provide an answer. In case it's not really <tr>, consider updating the question with your real case because it's different.

Comment: `<Component ref={r => this.tableRef = r}...` and base your dom searches off that. I'm curious why you need clientOffset etc? Sounds like something that's going to easily break on different viewports, content, resizing etc without complex code (e.g. what a virtualization library does)

Comment: @Dominic, But I only have children in that component - of course rendering new component would be much easier but that's not my case. I need topOffset to set height of container to include exactly 12 items... Yes it's messy but I need something to start

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use React.cloneElement to set the refs for the children: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement
ex:

```
React.cloneElement(child, {ref: this.setChildRef})}
```

```
export default class Test extends React.Component {

  childrenRefs = {}

  setChildRef = index => el => this.childrenRefs[index] = el;

  showInfo = () => {
    console.log('children', Object.keys(this.childrenRefs).map(key => this.childrenRefs[key].offsetTop))
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        { React.Children.toArray(this.props.children).map((c, index) => React.cloneElement(
          c,
          {ref: this.setChildRef(index)},
        ))}
        <button onClick={this.showInfo} >test</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

here is a link to a full working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cf33ge   Open the console at the bottom right to see the output.

Comment: Thanks, it made me to convert my child components into classes, but it's still working so yay!

Answer (score 2):

`findDOMNode` expects an instance of `React.Component`. Components should be rendered with refs in order to get instances. Since refs aren't used in `<ChildComponent>/* ... */</ChildComponent>` children, they should be cloned with a ref.

If children are supposed to be class component elements and their amount doesn't change during parent component lifespan, the case can be simplified to:

```
childRefs = [...Array(React.Children.count(this.props.children))]
.map(() => React.createRef());

render() {
  return React.Children.map(this.props.children, ((child, i) => 
    React.cloneElement(child, { ref: this.childRefs[i] });
  )
}
```

DOM element is available as `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.childRefs[n].current)` when the component is mounted.

Comment: Thanks for answer, SlimSim was first with very similar solution, but your is still very helpful!