# React - Ref to child component from parent

Tags: reactjs

Overview:
Example layout:
A B **C** D E F
*G H I J*

I have a grid of items (A,B,C,D,E,F). When an item is clicked (C), a list of sub items appears underneath (G,H,I,J). In order to make this accessible when tabbing, once an item is clicked, focus moves in to the list of sub items. However, once all of those items are tabbed through, I would like focus to move on to the next main item (D).

Problem:
I am adding refs to A,B,C,D,E and F, but I can't seem to access the refs in my grid in order to update the focus.

// Item

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.ref = React.createRef();
}
getItemRef() {
    return this.ref;
}
render() {
    return (
        <a ref={this.ref}>Stuff</a>
    );
}
```

// Parent

```
renderItems() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Item>
            <Item>
            <Item>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
render() {
    return (
        <Grid>
            {this.renderItems()}
        </Grid>
    );
}
```

// Grid

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, function(child) {
        console.log(typeof child.getItemRef === 'function'); // always false
    });
}
```

Comment: Does that help?

Comment: Yes. This is very close to this case, https://stackoverflow.com/a/54651393/3731501

Comment: Looks promising, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

`child` is React element object, not component instance. In order to access component instances, parent component should use refs and provide refs to items.

If children count doesn't change, refs array can have fixed length.

Grid component:

```
itemRefs = [...Array(React.Children(this.props.children).count)].map(() => React.createRef);

render() {
  return React.Children.map(this.props.children, ((item, i) => 
    React.cloneElement(child, { ref: this.itemRefs[i] });
  )
}
```

Parent component:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Grid>
            <Item>
            <Item>
            <Item>
        </Grid>
    );
}
```

Notice that parent component is expected to provide `<Item>` as `<Grid>` children without `<Fragment>` wrapper.

It's not a good practice to rely on grandchild ref, in case it's expected that `Grid` does something with nested `<a>`, `Item` should provide public API to access it (focus, blur, etc.), while `ref` property stays private.